# Is the existence of God a question within the purview of science?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, existence-of-god

Some people, including perhaps most philosophers, believe that the existence of God is a philosophical question, not a scientific one. But is it really? It seems to me that while the existence of a purely deistic God is not a scientific question, the existence of a theistic God, one who can do miracles, is definitely a scientifically testable notion. But what have philosophers said about this issue?

Comment: Conscious minds can’t exist without a material substance. We know this from experience and empirically, thus in a way this knowledge is scientific. If God does exist, He must be material. The standard objection to not being able to disprove minds not existing within a body is mental masturbation from philosophers and should be dismissed swiftly. One can’t disprove an infinite number of things.

Comment: yes, this has never come up before.

Comment: In Western world, theology is the "science of God", but it does not make many progress since the beginning...

Comment: You claim you think that a theistic God is a testable notion. What test are you imaging would prove/disprove the existence of such a God.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "... the existence of a theistic God, one who can do miracles, > is definitely a scientifically testable notion."

A Popperian would say that science requires all hypotheses to be not only testable but falsifiable.  There is no way to show that the existence of a "theistic God" that can do miracles is false, only corroborate it's truth.  In which case this question does not fall within the remit of science.